# Why am I getting Value Error here? (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to make a CRUD application in Django. My emp view is returning none where it should return HttpResponse. Here's my code.

```
def emp(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save()
                return redirect('/show')
            except:
                pass
        else:
            form = EmployeeForm()
        return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})
```

and here's my error.

```
The view employee.views.emp didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: If the request method is not post, what will the view return?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting a POST request in written code. but not hitting route with the POST request method.
your `request.method == "POST"` statement getting false so your view returning a None value instead of HttpResponse.